# Delete OAuth2 token in Thunderbird e-mail client

Tags: thunderbird, oauth2

I am using Thunderbird to access my Google Mail. I use OAuth2 to  authenticate. I am doing some testing and want to delete the OAuth2 token Thunderbird is using so that I am forced to re-authenticate.

How do I delete this OAuth2 token in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is Tools > options > Security > Passwords > saved passwords  and search on "auth"

Comment: The full path in my Thunderbird was `oauth://accounts.google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

And re-add the email account after you delete the OAuth token i.e do not re-start Thunderbird, otherwise Thunderbird adds the old Oauth token back in when you re-start, so effectively you have to delete and write a new OAuth token in the same session